# Aptitude conflicts with apt-get

Tags: apt, aptitude

I am using both apt-get and aptitude and it seems that they do not have the same policy for the old kernels management.

`apt-get` automatically installed two kernels: *3.13.0-36* (after a `dist-upgrade`) and *3.13.0-32* (the original one).

When I ask aptitude for updates, it tells me it needs to install the old kernel *3.13.0-35*. I accept but then, when I run `apt-get autoremove`, kernel *3.13.0-35* is marked as unnecessary for the system.

So here is my question: why is there those differences between `apt-get` and `aptitude` and what is the Ubuntu policy regarding to the old kernel management?

Which solution is best: `apt-get` or `aptitude`?